# Error while getting access key age using lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I have to get the active days for IAM secrets as per user and it should alert me before 70 days. I have below python which is working on my local:

```
min_age = 10
max_age = 90
user_list = []
maxage_users = []
slackchannel = os.environ['slackchannel']
hook_url = os.environ['hook_url']
account_id = boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()["Account"]
user = (f'user-{account_id}')
client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.list_users()
for x in response['Users']:
    if x['UserName'] !=  user:
        user_list.append(x['UserName'])

for username in user_list:
    res = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username)
    accesskeydate = res['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['CreateDate'].date()
    currentdate = date.today()
    active_days = currentdate - accesskeydate
    #print(active_days.days)
    days_remaining = max_age - active_days.days
    if active_days.days > min_age:
        maxage_users.append(username)

    #print(maxage_users)

message = (f'Found users "{maxage_users}" in account "{account_id}" User keys expires in:"{days_remaining}" days')
print(message)
```

but when I try to execute it using lambda function its throwing an below error:

```
[ERROR] NameError: name 'days_remaining' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Lambda code is as follows:

```
min_age = 10
max_age = 90
user_list = []
maxage_users = []
slackchannel = os.environ['slackchannel']
hook_url = os.environ['hook_url']
account_id = boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()["Account"]
user = (f'user-{account_id}')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    response = client.list_users()
    for x in response['Users']:
        if x['UserName'] !=  user:
            user_list.append(x['UserName'])

    for username in user_list:
        res = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username)
        accesskeydate = res['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['CreateDate'].date()
        currentdate = date.today()
        active_days = currentdate - accesskeydate
        #print(active_days.days)
        days_remaining = max_age - (active_days.days)
        if active_days.days > min_age:
            maxage_users.append(username)
        
print(f'{maxage_users} {days_remaining}')  
message = (f'Found users "{maxage_users}" in account "{account_id}" User keys expires in:"{days_remaining}" days')
print(message)
```

Comment: The only way that your code will produce that error is if the line `for username in user_list:` produces no iterations, which means that the line `for x in response['Users']:` produced no iterations.  That means that your call to `response = client.list_users()` is either returning no users, or none that pass the test `if x['UserName'] !=  user:`. This is likely because you are running with different permissions inside the lambda than on your local machine, or possibly even running in a different account (I work with three of them).

Comment: ...btw, I don't see anywhere here where you've set `user`.